# C# - How do I create a single standalone .exe file rather than an install file?

Tags: publish

Currently when I publish my windows app I am creating an install file.  What works best for our team is an .exe file that they can double click without installing anything.  It's not a very big or complicated app.

How do I create a single standalone .exe file?

When I coded in C# years ago I would just get the exe from the debug or release folders, but that no longer works.